# Escape [ in a element name in xml file

Tags: xml, escaping

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I need to form a element whose name begin with '[' and end with ']'. Something like this

```
<element_name>
   <[name-with-brackets] atributte1="value" />
</element_name>
```

Is there any way to scape those brackets characters in name of the element. I know I can escape them in the value of an atributte o in the data of the elemente with

```
&#91;  -->  <Element_name atribute="&#91;name-with-brackets&#93;" />
```

In my sample:

```
<element_name>
   <&#91;name-with-brackets&#93; atributte1="value" />
</element_name>
```

but it doesn't work with the element name

thanks

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Name it's not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can't do that, according to [**specs**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn):

> The first character of a Name **MUST** be a NameStartChar, and any other
>   characters **MUST** be NameChars; this mechanism is used to prevent names
>   from beginning with European (ASCII) digits or with basic combining
>   characters.

```
NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] 
                      | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF]
                      | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] 
                      | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF]
                      | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]

NameChar ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 
                           | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
```

> Document authors are encouraged to use names which are meaningful
>   words or combinations of words in natural languages, and to avoid
>   symbolic or white space characters in names. Note that COLON,
>   HYPHEN-MINUS, FULL STOP (period), LOW LINE (underscore), and MIDDLE
>   DOT are explicitly permitted.